# Why 'If they are to be woven'?

Tags: future-time

I am just practising some English grammar. Here is the question I am confused about:

> **Fibres of hair and wool are not continuous and must normally be spun
>   into thread _____ woven into textile fabrics.**
>
> (A) as are they
>
> (B) when to be
>
> (C) that they are
>
> (D) if they are to be

The correct answer is (D). Why?

Comment: If you work by elimination, you discard (A) and (C) as ungrammatical, I think (the former puts the verb in front of 'they', the latter has 'that' out of place).  Between the remaining (B) and (D), the former sounds wrong because the subclause has no subject (making it ambiguous between *fibers* and *thread*).  That's how I read it, anyway.

Comment: @VictorB - I agree with what you're saying for the most part, but I think (B) and (C) are the ungrammatical options.

Comment: @J.R. I agree with you. While D. is the best fit, A. could work as well. It largely depends on context.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Am I right : " Be to +infinitive " is commonly used in news reports to talk about event that are likely to happen. like : "police are to search every home in the area"

Comment: @Cardinal: Not sure about *likely to happen*; I was taught that in such instances 'to be' means a convention or a pre-existing agreement.

Comment: @Cardinal It's a BE + to + verb idiom. Means expected, supposed, assigned to do.

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly, you're asking why the other three are wrong:

> A) as are they

This answer has transposed the words *are* and *they*. To be grammatically correct, this form would have to be referring to a shared characteristic between objects. For example: *We're wearing blue jerseys, **as are they***.

> B) when to be

The word *when* is what throws this off. If the sentence is going to use an interval (using *when*) then it must properly define it so it may tie into the rest of the sentence (such as *...when they are to be...* which defines the interval as preceding its weaving), or it should drop the interval altogether to allow the conditional to stand on its own (...*spun into thread to be woven into*...).

> C) that they are

We have an extra pronoun that doesn't refer to anything which makes sense. If *they* refers to the fibers then *that* is wrong as we need something like an interval to connect the clauses. If *that* refers to thread, then the *they* needs to be dropped because it absorbs the meaning *that* should be shifting to *are).

Comment: The first could be correct if changed to *"as they are"* = *"while/when" they are*

Answer (score 1):

You might actually want the reason that D is the current answer.

> Fibres of hair and wool are not continuous and must normally be spun into thread **if they are to be** woven into textile fabrics.

Because *is/are + to infinitive* is a way to refer to future time. It sounds rather stiff and overly 'business formal' and, to some extent, outdated.

See [Ten ways of expressing the future in English](https://gramorak.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/10-ways-of-expressing-the-future/)

> 7.1. BE + to + infinitive
>
> This form is not common in informal conversation. It refers to something that is to happen in the future as a plan or decree, normally by some authority other than the subject of the sentence:
>
> 23. A new theatre is to be built in Andover next year.

So, here the machine (or person) doing the spinning  is 'the authority' over the process of spinning *fibres of hair and wool*.

This authoritarian tone is probably another reason it's not popular in today's English. Sounds like something you'd find in a communist setting.

The website goes on to say it is used in news reporting. But you will find it elsewhere, as in this sentence. It works like a future passive construction,so you can name or omit the agent (the "authority").